# $("#id") retuning non-null value even if a tag with such an id does not exist

Tags: jquery

I am doing

```
var tag = $("#foo");
if(tag != null) {
 // do something
}
```

the thing is, if even if the tag does not exist when the script is first executed, the value of tag variable is non-null and hence it breaks the code.

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery selectors never return null - you get an empty jQuery collection. You can test for:

```
if(tag.length){
    // do something
}
```

`tag.length` will be zero if nothing was found, which is a false value in JavaScript.

Even better, if all you do is simple jQuery operations you don't have to check the result at all - operations on an empty fail silently to allow chaining:

```
$('#id').show().find('.field').css('color', 'red')
 .add('#otherId').text('done');
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to check the `length` property to see if an element exists.

For a better way, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery) Stackoverflow thread.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do the same thing by using ***size***..

```
if ( $(selector).size() > 0 ) {  
  //do something  
 }
```